# $timeout in a directive link function

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

So I'm using this directive to collapse a variable height card in Ionic. The directive grabs the auto height and changes it to a defined height so it can then be collapsed to 0 with a css animation. It was working fine for my needs, but now I need to use `ng-src` to dynamically load an image within the card. What's happening is the image is being loaded *after* the directive, so the image loads and overflows the card.

Directive:

```
.directive('collapse', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function ($scope, ngElement, attributes) {
            var element = ngElement[0];


            $timeout(function(){                
                $scope.$watch(attributes.collapse, function (collapse) {
                            var newHeight = collapse ? 0 : getElementAutoHeight();

                            element.style.height = newHeight +"px";
                            ngElement.toggleClass('collapsed', collapse);
                        });

            function getElementAutoHeight() {
                var currentHeight = getElementCurrentHeight();

                element.style.height = 'auto';
                var autoHeight = getElementCurrentHeight();

                element.style.height = currentHeight +"px";
                getElementCurrentHeight(); // Force the browser to recalc height after moving it back to normal

                return autoHeight;
            }

            function getElementCurrentHeight() {
                return element.offsetHeight
            }
         });
      }
    };
}])
```

and HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy : '-'" collapse="item.deleted">
    <div class="list card">
        <img class="full-image" ng-src="{{item.image}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I've injected `$timeout` and leaving the interval blank in hopes it will wait until the DOM is loaded, but it seems no matter how I use it, the directive still explicitly sets the height of the element in css before the image child element is rendered. How can I delay the setting of element height until after `ng-src` is loaded in each `ng-repeat` item?

Comment: where is you use $timeout ? here is syntax `$timeout(function(){//yourcode}`

Comment: I tried it wrapped around the watch, around everything, etc.  None worked.  I've edited the original post to reflect one of the attempts.

Comment: Putting `$watch` inside a `$timeout` only delays the *registering* of the watch handler until the next digest cycle. That won't guarantee that the CSS manipulation occurs after the load of the image. The browser fires the "load" event on the `<img>` element when a resource has been loaded. Use that event to sequence the changes to the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so thanks to Thai's input, I have a working solution:

```
.directive('collapse', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function ($scope, ngElement, attributes) {
            var element = ngElement[0];

            var img = element.querySelector('.full-image');

            angular.element(img).bind('load', function() {

               var autoHeight = getElementAutoHeight();

               element.style.height = autoHeight + "px";


            }); 

            $scope.$watch(attributes.collapse, function (collapse) {
                var newHeight = collapse ? 0 : getElementAutoHeight();

                element.style.height = newHeight +"px";
                ngElement.toggleClass('collapsed', collapse);
            });

            function getElementAutoHeight() {
                var currentHeight = getElementCurrentHeight();

                element.style.height = 'auto';
                var autoHeight = getElementCurrentHeight();

                element.style.height = currentHeight +"px";
                getElementCurrentHeight(); // Force the browser to recalc height after moving it back to normal

                return autoHeight;
            }

            function getElementCurrentHeight() {
                return element.offsetHeight
            }
        }
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, angular **$timeout** without an $interval will not wait for the DOM tree to load, basically, what it does is waiting for the current **digest cycle** to finish before executing the function in the first parameter. By doing so, it will allow the your code to wait till the directive finish compile and render before calculating the height of the div.

However, there is no guarantee that the image will be loaded by that time. Images are loaded by the browser independently from DOM rendering, therefore, to calculate the height of the container having images precisely, you should make use of **JS Image Object** and the **load event**. Once the images are fully loaded, then you can update the height.

Also, for your directive, I don't think you need to calculate the height every times the collapse variable changed (inside the watch), you can simply wait till the image being loaded, calculate the height once, store it inside the scope object, and reuse it whenever the collapse variable change.